# Reading only some columns when using readHTMLTable to get tables from a website

Tags: html, r, subset

I am trying to read the table from this website.

http://www.databaseolympics.com/games/gamessport.htm?g=1&sp=ATH

The problem is I only want the first column (Event) and the last column (Medal) to be read.
This is my code and result:

```
 temp_URL<-'http://www.databaseolympics.com/games/gamessport.htm?g=1&sp=ATH'
tab<-readHTMLTable(temp_URL, which=3,colClasses = c('factor',NULL,NULL,NULL,'factor'))
head(tab)

     Event         Athlete Country    Result  Medal
1 100m Men       Tom Burke     USA      12.0   GOLD
2            Fritz Hofmann     DEU 12.2 est. SILVER
3             Francis Lane     USA      12.6 BRONZE
4          Alajos Szokolyi     HUN 12.6 est. BRONZE
5 400m Men       Tom Burke     USA      54.2   GOLD
6          Herbert Jamison     USA       n/a SILVER
```

As you can see it returns all the columns of the table. I read on the R Documentation that using colClasses and stating a Null value should make R ignore that column but it is not working for me. I realize once you have the data in R it is very easy to just create a new data frame with the desired columns:

```
tab<-data.frame(tab$Event,tab$Medal)
     head(tab)
      tab.Event tab.Medal
    1  100m Men      GOLD
    2              SILVER
    3              BRONZE
    4              BRONZE
    5  400m Men      GOLD
    6              SILVER
```

I would really like to avoid this extra step and find a way in which only the desired data comes in to R, the reason for this is beause this page is a part of a code that needs to read thousands of pages and that extra step could be time consuming when running for multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use list instead of vector:

```
temp_URL<-'http://www.databaseolympics.com/games/gamessport.htm?g=1&sp=ATH'

tab<-readHTMLTable(temp_URL, which=3,colClasses = list("factor",NULL,NULL,NULL,"factor"),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

head(tab)
                V1     V2
        1 100m Men   GOLD
        2          SILVER
        3          BRONZE
        4          BRONZE
        5 400m Men   GOLD
        6          SILVER
```